# VTK built using TBB gives DLL load error when vtk module is imported in python 3.10.8

Tags: vtk

I'm building VTK 9.2.2 using TBB backend from source, my generated wheel work fine on Linux but on Windows it gives me error.

VTK built using TBB gives DLL load error when vtk module is imported in python 3.10.8

Details:

```
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\DE-Python\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 31, in <module>
    all_m = importlib.import_module('vtkmodules.all')
  File "C:\DE-Python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\DE-Python\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\all.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .vtkCommonCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I tried to add VTK Dll's location using os.add_dll_directory() but still getting same error.

There is an open issue for this: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18472

None of the workarounds mentioned here work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue in VTK.

There is a bug in VTK when compiling on python 3.10+ see here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18472

The current workaround for this as mentioned by some VTK experts/users is:

1. To create a file: C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\ _build_paths.py and add tbb and vtk dll paths to it.
2. Second option is to add tbb and vtk DLLs paths using os.add_dll_directory()